# Recover ASPX file after corruption

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, corruption, recover

I really hope you can help...
Visual Studio 2010 crashed on me earlier this morning. Normally when that happens I will get the option to recover the files, unfortunately this never appeared and when I opened the solution the aspx page I was working on has lost about 99% of it's coding (nearly a week work with 4000 lines!!!).

I have checked in the Visual Studio folder and there are no backup files so that route is out the window.
For some reason the .cs file that is associated with that aspx file is fine but the aspx code is gone.
Annoyingly this page had been stuck into version controlling but just not committed yet (yes I know, live and learn...) so that option is out the window too.

I have tried using .NET Reflector to reverse engineer the dll file but that has only given me back the .cs files which I already have.

So I guess what I am really asking is...Is there anyway to recover just the aspx pages and not just the .cs files?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in a corporate environment? If so your admin may be able to roll back the files affected.

Comment: Thanks, it is a corporate environment but unfortunately these files are away from the automated backup so the roll back can't happen. It is just so frustrating that the .cs and designer.cs files associated with the aspx page are fine but the aspx page is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check-out my answer here: [Lost the content of ASPX page on computer restart before Saving the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344290/lost-the-content-of-aspx-page-on-computer-restart-before-saving-the-file/16740939#16740939)

NEXT TIME YOU WILL BE SAVED ... :D

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a link to any answer? Interested in finding out though, no doubt I will stupidly do something that will need it in the future :)

Comment: Cheers, I don't know why I never thought of that before! Oh well, I will try to remember that for next time (although I hope I never have to remember!). I will accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a backup or the ASPX file was committed to source code control (e.g. TFS, git, SVN), the file is likely lost.

Even if your organization frowns on commits of partially implemented code, you can always use your own source control system, such as a local git or SVN repository. It does not help you now but it may help in the future.

Comment: Unfortunately my only other backup that was on my local machine too which was over written with the corrupted files with my auto backup tool! . The annoying thing is I was going to commit it to source control this afternoon as well. Sigh, oh well I guess I will just need to live, learn and chalk it up to experience and make sure I have a local SVN as well as on the server from now on.

Comment: It is just so frustrating that the .cs and designer.cs files associated with the aspx page are fine but the contents of aspx page is gone

Comment: Comment By STEM IN DIE BOS: Try and look at your temporary internet files somewhere here: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vx.xxx.x\Temporary...

Comment: Ah good thinking, that will narrow down my search slightly. Thank you. Fingers crossed lol.

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty method is if you were previewing your page, then copy the source of that page and past in your aspx page.

If not then I am sorry to say that you have lost your changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't previewing it at the time, I even tried in vain looking at the localhost folder hoping that it might be there. Alas, nothing. Oh well, looks like I have a lot of catching up to do. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

You might try doing a file search on your system for a temp file from the right time period.  There's no guarantee, of course, but it's possible that it might still be hanging around, even if VS didn't retain it.

Comment: Ah good thinking, thank you! I shall go and have a look now. Fingers crossed!